# Change default attribute of ADF component

Tags: oracle, sorting

We have deployed a huge ADF application, and now the customer want's to select multiple columns in tables, when sorting.

I have found out how (`columnSelection="multiple"`), and then there is a "advanced" sort page available with the panel collection  - works like a charm.

The trouble is: The application that we have deployed is huge. Several years of development. Is it possible to change the default `columnSelection` property? As of now, the default value is `default(none)`, and I would like to change this to `default(multiple)`.

I this isn't possible, a script could do the job, but we want the attribute to be set to `default(multiple)` for every table added in the future.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned is a useful usecase but it doesnt look like adf allows that at the moment. If they did, then users would begin to change the defaults wrt iterators on the pageDefs which might then prove to be a nightmare.